# What am I doing wrong with racoon on ubuntu precise?

Tags: 12.04, vpn, ipsec

I have a working racoon ipsec vpn setup on an ubuntu lucid server. To set it up, I just did an apt-get on the ipsectools package and configured the racoon.conf file.

If I take the exact same steps, but also install the racoon package in precise (it's separated from ipsec-tools in precise) and use an identical config, the racoon daemon won't even start.

If you set logging in racoon to debug, you see the following in the syslog:

```
Nov 21 00:42:02 vpnhub2 racoon: DEBUG: getsainfo params: loc='ANONYMOUS' rmt='ANONYMOUS' peer='NULL' client='NULL' id=1
Nov 21 00:42:02 vpnhub2 racoon: INFO: Resize address pool from 0 to 100
Nov 21 00:42:02 vpnhub2 racoon: DEBUG: open /var/run/racoon/racoon.sock as racoon management.
Nov 21 00:42:02 vpnhub2 racoon: INFO: x.x.x.x[4500] used for NAT-T
Nov 21 00:42:02 vpnhub2 racoon: INFO: x.x.x.x[4500] used as isakmp port (fd=6)
Nov 21 00:42:02 vpnhub2 racoon: INFO: x.x.x.x[500] used for NAT-T
Nov 21 00:42:02 vpnhub2 racoon: INFO: x.x.x.x[500] used as isakmp port (fd=7)
Nov 21 00:42:02 vpnhub2 racoon: DEBUG: pk_recv: retry[0] recv() 
Nov 21 00:42:02 vpnhub2 racoon: DEBUG: got pfkey X_SPDDUMP message
Nov 21 00:42:02 vpnhub2 racoon: DEBUG: pfkey X_SPDDUMP failed: No such file or directory
```

Racoon crashes shortly after you start it. It does this whether I use my config or the default one installed with the package.

I have tried this on a rackspace cloud server and a vm on virtualbox, using the 32bit and  64bit versions - same result.

Am I doing something wrong, or is the current version of racoon not working?

Comment: What do you mean by "Racoon crashes"?

Comment: the process terminates immediately after the "pfkey X_SPDDUMP failed" message appears in the syslog.

Comment: I'm confused, is this precise or lucid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Racoon missd the pf key file. Specify this in you'rconfiguration file and racoon should work again.  If it still doesn't work post your config file to pastebin.cim and share the link here.

Comment: Ahhhh brilliant, I'll look into this and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks, you were right. I manaully specified this in my config on precise. I'm nnot sure why that worked in Lucid though.